# If (someVar And 8) = 8 Then -- what does this mean?

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements

I'm working in some legacy VB code (.aspx page) and all over the place I see conditionals of this format:

```
If (someVar And {integer_x}) = {integer_x} Then
```

And I've seen all kinds of integers, but they all seem to be powers of 2 (8, 64, 256, 16384, etc.).

What does this code do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bitwise check. This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx) says it all.

(But link-only answers are frowned upon, so...)

When you do bitwise operations, you look for a bit that's "on", or has the value 1. If you look for `someVar And 8`, that's saying "does someVar have its 4th bit on from the right at the on position".

8 translates in binary as `0001000`. If `someVar` has a 1 in that position, the logical operator `And` will return `0001000`, or 8. And then you check for equality. Note that `someVar` can still have other bits on. It could be worth 9 (`0001001`), and that would still mean the condition is true.

Now, unless this is for an interface with an electronic system or parsing raw data, I'd say that's a really outdated way of doing what Enum with the Flags attribute can do.

Let's fast-forward to today:

```
<Flags()> _
Enum PizzaToppings
  Sauce = 1
  Pepperoni = 2
  Mushrooms = 4
  Peppers = 8
  Bacon = 16
  Ham = 32
  Cheese = 64
  Pineapple = 128
End Enum

'...

Dim myToppings As PizzaToppings = PizzaToppings.Sauce Or PizzaToppings.Cheese 'Use Or to combine or + 

'...

If myToppings.HasFlag(PizzaToppings.Sauce) Then
    addSauce()
End If
```

If you don't want to bother with powers, you can also do a bit shift:

```
1 << 0 is 2^0 is 1
1 << 1 is 2^1 is 2
1 << 2 is 2^2 is 4
1 << 3 is 2^3 is 8
```

Thus:

```
Enum PizzaToppings
  Sauce = 1 << 0
  Pepperoni = 1 << 1
'...
```

Comment: @Steve I wanted to get the basic answer first :)

Comment: @MPelletier - yes, this is a legacy system built in the late 90's :)

Comment: @jbyrd I guess some old ASP code got ported to ASP.NET at some point then.

Comment: This is helpful, though the reason for a bitwise check is still slightly confusing to me. If you can give comparison examples of the same conditional using a bitwise check and then using Enums, that would be perfect, and I'll definitely accept your answer.

Comment: What is the meaning of `<<` at the bottom of your post?

Comment: @AaronFranke I do what's called a [bit shift](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7haw1dex.aspx). It "shifts" or moves a value (in my case always 1) to the left by the amount specified. `1 << 3` moves the 1 by 3 spaces, to the 4th position, and that becomes an 8.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @Trevor

Comment: Ya its one of those places where "English" doesn't work @MPelletier

Comment: @Trevor That totally slipped past me. Not long ago I had to find a way to explain that in plain language for laymen. Fun times.

Comment: Ha.. I can't imagine how you did it. @MPelletier

Comment: It may be helpful for those who are curious that the enums in the example are set to sequential powers of 2 (instead of just 1, 2, 3...) in order that if you want to combine some of them (let's say you want sauce, pepporoni, *and* mushrooms), you can refer to the value as the addition of those numbers (in my example, it would be 1 + 2 + 4 = 7), and the resulting number of any addition of numbers will never conflict with any other single value, or be ambiguous. Great answer and example; super helpful - thank you!

Comment: @jbyrd That's it!